# Want to revert back from version 12.3 to 12.1 but kernels no longer run in 12.1

Tags: parallelization, crash

I upgraded from 12.1 to 12.3 and then Mathematica began randomly crashing intermittently. It's not reproducible:  it crashed when I was rotating a 3D plot twice, crashed once when I tried to save a notebook, and multiple times idle not executing anything.  It just completely and instantly vanishes from the screen without any errors or messages.  I don't need any of the features with this upgrade and suspect it's a version issue and would just as soon use 12.1 still on my machine until this is fixed but when I run 12.1, the 4 kernels no longer start up and I need them running for my work.  It crashes at least once a day and causes me to loose work.

Can anyone explain to me how to get the kernels running again under 12.1?

Comment: I suggest that you contact Wolfram support for help with this problem.

Comment: I also have the same problem that prior versions of Mathematica are not launching subkernels under the latest version of MacOS. Under Mojave, prior versions of Mathematica launch subkernels properly. Since 12.3.1 is a hot mess in terms of front end stability, this is not good.

Comment: This cannot be answered without more detail about you setup. Do you happen to run under macos Big Sur? As I understand it, Mathematica 12.1 requires Catalina or earlier (see https://support.wolfram.com/51966). Not sure, though. Also, IIRC, version 12.1 is not ready for native support of Apple Silicon...